# How can I log all exception in application where I use try/catch?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

Suppose I have a try/catch block like below:

```
try
{           
    // Some Code
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblError.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

I have a lot of codes like this in my application. I want to save time not to change these codes.

Is there any way that I log all exception that happen in these blocks in my application?

Comment: if you have a lot of try catch blocks in your application, then you really should rethink things. You should unit test and validate data so much you should rarely ever have to use them. You should really look into ELMAH for error handling, this will help you a lot.

Comment: Do you rethrow the exceptions or simply swallow them like that?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov just like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use post build event IL Injection to inject log calls in each catch section.
check this link - 
 [ILGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx/)

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the lblError.TextChanged event and log the error in there.

```
lblError.TextChanged += (sender, e) => { yourLogger.log("Error -" + lblError.Text); }
```